# Execution time is different for the same query. What should be the reason?

Tags: mysql

When I execute the same query multiple time in Mysql console. Execution times vary all the times.

I can understand the difference if its in milliseconds. But sometimes same query take 1 second and sometimes same query take 5 seconds.

What should be the reason in this case ?

Comment: Maybe your network connection?

Comment: Even if you give us more details, there are many factors that would affect execution. While your query is running, how many other queries are running? How much memory is available at that moment? Has the data changed? And so on, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

MANY reasons:

- the result was cached and the cache got cleared
- the table is locked (maybe because it is executing another big query)
- the disk is slow or busy doing other things
- you are running out of memory
- the results might be changing (pull 1k record vs pulling 500k records)
- the Server is remote, so you might have network problems
- it is the ghost in the machine